# Getting Keyboard Input

Tags: java, input, console, keyboard

How do I get simple keyboard input (an integer) from the user in the console in Java? I accomplished this using the `java.io.*` stuff, but it says it is deprecated.

How should I do it now?

Comment: Be specific. The '`java.io.*` stuff' isn't deprecated. Only `DataInputStream.readLine()`. There is still `BufferedReader.readLine()`, as well as the other suggestions you've been given here.

Answer (score 80):

You can use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class

Import first :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Then you use like this.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter an integer");
int myint = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Side note : If you are using `nextInt()` with `nextLine()` you probably could have some trouble cause `nextInt()` does not read the last newline character of input and so `nextLine()` then is not gonna to be executed with desired behaviour. Read more in how to solve it in this previous question [Skipping nextLine using nextInt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint).

Comment: It says cannot find symbol Scanner

Comment: @user1342573 you have to import `java.util.Scanner`

Comment: Is "in" keyboard in Java and "out" screen?

Comment: @Doeser they are class members variables (static) defined in System class,

Comment: Why you use keyboard instead of in?

Comment: @mostvenerablesir it's a variable dude!

Answer (score 21):

You can use Scanner class like this:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

    //For string

    String text= scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println(text);

    //for int

    int num= scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can also make it with [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) if you want to validate user input, like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
class Areas {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        float PI = 3.1416f;
        int r=0;
        String rad; //We're going to read all user's text into a String and we try to convert it later
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //Here you declare your BufferedReader object and instance it.
        System.out.println("Radius?");
        try{
            rad = br.readLine(); //We read from user's input
            r = Integer.parseInt(rad); //We validate if "rad" is an integer (if so we skip catch call and continue on the next line, otherwise, we go to it (catch call))
            System.out.println("Circle area is: " + PI*r*r + " Perimeter: " +PI*2*r); //If all was right, we print this
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Write an integer number"); //This is what user will see if he/she write other thing that is not an integer
            Areas a = new Areas(); //We call this class again, so user can try it again
           //You can also print exception in case you want to see it as follows:
           // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Because Scanner class won't allow you to do it, or not that easy...

And to validate you use "try-catch" calls.

Comment: I don't understand why you say "Because Scanner class won't allow you to do it, or not that easy..."? IMO you can?

Comment: Also if you wanna call that class again (or to continue execution) you should call "a.main(null)" after instantiating, or just do  "Areas.main(null)"

Comment: @KillBill thanks for your comment, I had forgotten about this question, in a few days I'll try to edit it with a better explanation, when I wrote this answer I was starting my high school studies, today I work in an IT company and I'll write this in the best way I can; back then I was a complete newbie, I can't edit it right now because I have some work to do, but I promise I'll edit and let you know.

Comment: @KillBill Thanks for that method about `Areas.main(null)` but in that case if you want to reuse the code, you should place it inside a method, the code in my answer was made on the main method because I tried to make a [mcve] so anyone who came up my answer could easily copy-paste it and see what it does w/o extra work

Comment: @Frakcool What i wanted to say is your code as is doesn't continue execution. Anyways no worries mate..as your wish

Comment: You still need to fix this. `Scanner` can do all this, and without the `try-catch` structure: and if you're going to use `try-catch` you should at least catch the specific `NumberFormatException`, not just `Exception`.

Answer (score 12):

### You can use Scanner class

To Read from **Keyboard** (*Standard Input*) You can use **Scanner** is a class in `java.util` package.

`Scanner` package used for obtaining the input of the primitive types like `int, double` etc. and `strings`. It is the easiest way to read input in a Java program, though not very efficient.

1. To create an `object` of `Scanner` class, we usually pass the
   predefined object `System.in`, which represents the standard input
   stream (*Keyboard*).

For example, this code allows a user to read a number from System.in:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     int i = sc.nextInt();
```

Some Public methods in `Scanner` class.

- `hasNext()`  Returns true if this scanner has another token in its
  input.
- `nextInt()` Scans the next token of the input as an int.
- `nextFloat()` Scans the next token of the input as a float.
- `nextLine()` Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.
- `nextDouble()` Scans the next token of the input as a double.
- `close()` Closes this scanner.

For more details of [Public methods in Scanner class.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Scanner)

Example:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;                      //importing class

class ScannerTest {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);       // Scanner object

    System.out.println("Enter your rollno");
    int rollno = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    String name = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Enter your fee");
    double fee = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Rollno:" + rollno + " name:" + name + " fee:" + fee);
    sc.close();                              // closing object
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Scanner to get the next line and do whatever you need to do with the line entered. You can also use JOptionPane to popup a dialog asking for inputs.

Scanner example:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter something > ");
String inputString = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("You entered : ");
System.out.println(inputString);
```

JOptionPane example:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
     "Enter some text:");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You entered "+ input);
```

You will need these imports:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

A complete Java class of the above

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class GetInputs{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Scanner example
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter something > ");
        String inputString = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("You entered : ");
        System.out.println(inputString);

        //JOptionPane example
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        "Enter some text:");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You entered "+ input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Import: `import java.util.Scanner;`

Define your variables: `String name; int age;`

Define your scanner: `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`

If you want to type:

- Text: `name = scan.nextLine();`
- Integer: `age = scan.nextInt();`

Close scanner if no longer needed: `scan.close();`

Answer (score 2):

If you have Java 6 (You should have, btw) or higher, then simply do this :

```
 Console console = System.console();
 String str = console.readLine("Please enter the xxxx : ");
```

Please remember to do :

```
 import java.io.Console;
```

Thats it!

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner; //import the framework


Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //opens a scanner, keyboard
System.out.print("Enter a number: "); //prompt the user
int myInt = input.nextInt(); //store the input from the user
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Fairly self-explanatory. I commented the code so you can read it. :)

Comment: @nachokk I actually typed it up while you posted yours. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Add line:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Then create an object of `Scanner` class:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Now you can call any time:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
```

This will store `integer` value from your keyboard.

Comment: You can call `nextInt()` instead of `nextLine()`.

Answer (score 1):

In java we can read input values in 6 ways:

1. **Scanner Class**
2. **BufferedReader**
3. **Console class**
4. **Command line**
5. **AWT, String, GUI**
6. **System properties**

> 1. **Scanner class:** present in java.util.*; package and it has many methods, based your input types you can utilize those methods. a. nextInt() b. nextLong() c. nextFloat() d. nextDouble() e. next() f. nextLine(); etc...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a :");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter b :");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        
        int c = a + b;
        System.out.println("Result: "+c);
    }
}
```

> 2. **BufferedReader class:** present in java.io.*; package & it has many method, to read the value from the keyboard use **"readLine()"** : this method reading one line at a time.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        System.out.println("Enter a :");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter b :");
        int b = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        
        int c = a + b;
        System.out.println("Result: "+c);
    }
}
```