# Program outputting Too many lines?

Tags: java, output

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sales   
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

 String[] name = new String[5]; 
 double[] sales = new double[5]; 

     for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {  
     System.out.println ("What is the name of the person?");
     name[i] = scan.nextLine();
     System.out.println ("How much did he/she sell?");
     sales[i] = scan.nextDouble();
     }
     for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {  
     System.out.println (name[j] + " sold " + sales[j]);
     }


     int sum = 0; 
     for (double k : sales){
     sum+=k;
     }

     double avg = sum / 5; 
     System.out.println ("The average sales is: " + avg);

     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     if (sales[i] >= avg){ 
     System.out.println (name[i] + " sold more than the average sales.");
     }
     }
 }
```

}

(This code is only a portion of the program.. sorry if it's kinda messy[im a beginner])
This is the issue...
It outputs like this:
What is the name of the person?
Patrick
How much did he/she sell?
8000
**What is the name of the person?

How much did he/she sell?**

The lines in bold are the issue. I want to enter a different name and amount, but it asks me twice at the same time. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Oh yes take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538182/getting-keyboard-input/17538216#17538216) and special to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/2415194)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `nextDouble` you have to call `scan.NextLine()` to get rid of a end of line character that was left in the output.

The `scan.nextDouble` method reads just the number, nothing else. And because the user "confirms" his input by hitting enter, he will also send a end-of-line character there. The for loop would then take this end-of-line character as input for the first question. Hence - after the double is read, just call an empty `scan.NextLine()` and you will be fine :-) .

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/2415194) for a workaround