# Java - How do I get what key is currently pressed?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, keyboard, keylistener

Instead of using Swing's event-based `keyPressed(keyEvent e)` method to detect which keys are pressed on my keyboard, I would like to do a Thread that checks which keys are pressed every x seconds (so not getting the keys through the keyPressed event triggered by the OS).

I know how to do the thread, but I don't find any method/interface (I'm currently using KeyListener) to get which keys are pressed.

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: What UI toolkit are you using? Both Swing and SWT have methods with that signature.

Comment: Using a KeyListener is a lot more efficient than continuously “asking” if a key has been pressed not to forget the delay you are creating this way. So why exactly do you want it like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538182/getting-keyboard-input this might help you

Comment: @NikitaIvanov - That question covers scanning input from lines entered into the console. It does not cover this question.

Comment: Why do you want that? Is there an advantage you hope to obtain? Asking without having thought of any.

Comment: I use swing. The adventage is that I make a event based game, and I need a better control on the player moovements. If I use the event listener my character will move like typed letters moove on your computer when you let a key pressed :)

Comment: I don’t think there’s a bulletproof way of detecting auto-repeating keys from the user pressing a key in rapid succession in Java. I would suggest that your best bet is to filter out key events with the identical key code coming rapidly after each other. Probably `KeyEvent.getWhen()` will give you the best estimate of how close in time the events were.

Comment: `need a better control on the player moovements.` - you listen for the initial keyPressed and then you start a Timer to schedule the animation. On a keyReleased you stop the TImer. For example check out `KeyboardAnimtion` example found in [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/)