# I want to have a wait between println to wait for a keypress

Tags: java, keylistener

I have program where there's text that's being printed. I want to know how I can make it so that the text wait's with printing until I press enter.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538182/getting-keyboard-input

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the program, create a `Scanner` with `System.in` as its source:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Whenever you want to pause:

```
System.out.println("Press ENTER to continue..."); // optional
scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: This isthe simplest way to do it but may not work in all cases.